# Python Split a text into list

Tags: python, string, list, integer

I want to convert this

```
1:a,b,c
2:d,e,f
```

into this

```
[[1, ['a', 'b', 'c']],[2, ['d', 'e', 'f']]]
```

My code

```
letters = open("letters.txt")
alist = []
for line in favmovies:
    line = line.strip().split(":")
    line[0] = int(line[0])
    alist.append(line)
```

but it gives this instead

```
[[1, 'a,b,c'], [2, 'd,e,f']]
```

Can anyone please offer a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just split the second part of the array by ",".

```
letters = open("letters.txt")
alist = []
for line in favmovies:
    line = line.strip().split(":")
    line[0] = int(line[0])
    line[1] = line[1].split(',')
    list.append(line)
```

This gives me, with your example:

```
[1, ['a', 'b', 'c']] 
[2, ['d', 'e', 'f']]
```

And it preserves the overarching format of your original code.

Comment: @Hal sure, hope this helps!  If this answers your question, please mark it as correct by clicking the green checkmark.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That can be done with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like:

#### Code:

```
data = [[int(x[0]), [y.strip() for y in x[1].split(',')]]
        for x in (line.split(':') for line in letters)]
```

#### Test Code:

```
letters = ['1:a, b, c', '2: d, e, f']
data = [[int(x[0]), [y.strip() for y in x[1].split(',')]]
        for x in (line.split(':') for line in letters)]
print(data)
```

#### Results:

```
[[1, ['a', 'b', 'c']], [2, ['d', 'e', 'f']]]
```

Comment: I like your solution because this question exemplifies what list comprehension is good for, and because you preserve the logic of the OP's post (as I did in my answer) but illuminate how it can be coalesced pythonically.  There's a subtlety here: you give an alternative method, but your alternative maintains the original logic.  (Which is ideal, I think.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re` to condense the solution:

```
import re
data = [re.split('\W+', i.strip('\n')) for i in open("letters.txt")]
last_data = [[int(a), b] for a, *b in data]
```

Output:

```
[[1, ['a', 'b', 'c']], [2, ['d', 'e', 'f']]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
letters=open("letters.txt").read().split("\n")
output_list=[]
for el in letters:
    output_list.append([el.split(":")[0],el.split(":")[1].split(",")])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one loop approach:

```
print([list(map(lambda x: x.split(','), i.strip().split(':'))) for i in open('file.txt','r')])
```

output:

```
[[['1'], ['a', 'b', 'c']], [['2'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]]
```